# Как заменить черно-белую .png на цветную?

Tags: html, css, filter, png

Есть такая картинка в формате ".png" :

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На одном сайте увидел, что при наведении на изображение подобного формата,  изменяется его состояние (при наведении изображение становится цветным).

Как это реализовать без grayscale-фильтра в `css`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использовать картинку в качестве `background`, а затем при наведении менять расположение(`background-position`):

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background-image: url("https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/924/1*ECSuMpJxNLViTxUOounYlw.png");
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.v2 {
  background-position: -85px 0px;
}

.v3 {
  background-position: -170px 0px;
}

.v1:hover {
  background-position: 0 -86px;
}

.v2:hover  {
  background-position: -85px -84px;
}

.v3:hover  {
  background-position: -170px -84px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block v1"></div>
  <div class="block v2"></div>
  <div class="block v3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Да, несколько картинок в одной и менять их позиции, это и есть:

> Спрайты

Или на ховер менять в css background-image, что не так хорошо, ибо дергается при загрузке.